# Calculating subsection total in a table

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I am newbie to XSLT and I have a problem on calculating the subsection totals in a table. I am using XSLT 1.0. I am able to get the Grand Total from XML, but getting subsections has lot of ifs/else and conditions which its difficult to explain.
Please find the sample table and XML below.

So what am trying to do is compare the Document 1 to Document 2.
If the Recno matches in both document then those record goes into "Same".
If a Rec is there in Document1 and not in Document2 then it will go to "Add" section.
If a Rec is there in Document2 and not in Document1 then it will go to "Delete" section.

I tried searching everywhere but no luck so far. Any pointers are appreciated

My Output HTML Table should look like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Section         RecNo         Desc          Qty         Value   
----------------------------------------------------------------
Same             111        Desc1           1           $100.00
Same             444        Desc1           1           $200.00
Same             123        Desc1           1           $300.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
                          Same Total                    $600.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
Add             555         Desc1           1           $100.00
Add             999         Desc1           1           $100.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
                           Add Total                    $200.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
Delete          777         Desc1           1           $200.00
Delete          888         Desc1           1           $200.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
                           Delete Total                 $400.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
                         Grand Total                    $1200.00
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Logia xmlns="com.configsc">
  <DocHeader xmlns="com.configsc.docheader">
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>333</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>444</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>555</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>123</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$300.00</Value>
            </Downto>
        </Document>
        <Document>

            <Downto>
                <rec_no>222</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>444</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>777</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>888</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
             <Downto>
                <rec_no>123</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>$300.00</Value>
            </Downto>
        </Document>
    </Material>
  </DocHeader>
</Logia>
```

Comment: You definitely should post your input XML; you probably should post your desired output XML and what you've tried so far.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Meanwhile the xml is huge with 5K of lines and same with my xslt file, It has some 1K of code. Editing those to make generic might be time consuming

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example of your input **as code**. The contents of the table above will do just fine, provided the data is correct - which I suspect currently is not, since the grouping makes no sense. Also explain - or preferably show - what is the expected format of the output.

Comment: Also make sure you are familiar with the standard method of XSLT 1.0 grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: My appologies on my initial post which was not clear. Now i have posted with more clarify on what i need. Also i have updated the sample XML with the updated table too. Thanks all for your valueable comments. Appreciated.

Comment: "*If the Rec matches in both document*" What constitutes a match? I thought it would be `rec_no` - but you have a duplicate (111) in Document[2]. Not sure how that should be handled.

Comment: @michael.hor257k With your logic i am able to get what was needed. Thank you so much. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this may be a little too much for a single SO question. I have decided to simplify your input to the following:

```
<Logia>
  <DocHeader>
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>100.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>333</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc3</desc>
                <qty>3</qty>
                <Value>300.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>444</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc4</desc>
                <qty>4</qty>
                <Value>400.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>555</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc5</desc>
                <qty>5</qty>
                <Value>500.00</Value>
            </Downto>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>222</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc2</desc>
                <qty>2</qty>
                <Value>200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>100.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>444</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc4</desc>
                <qty>4</qty>
                <Value>400.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>777</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc7</desc>
                <qty>7</qty>
                <Value>700.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>888</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc8</desc>
                <qty>8</qty>
                <Value>800.00</Value>
            </Downto>
         </Document>
  </DocHeader>
</Logia>
```

**Note the removal of namespaces and the conversion of** `Value` **values to *numbers*.**

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="doc1" match="Document[1]/Downto" use="rec_no" />
<xsl:key name="doc2" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="rec_no" />

<xsl:template match="/Logia/DocHeader">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>RecNo</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- same -->
        <xsl:variable name="same" select="Document[1]/Downto[key('doc2', rec_no )]" />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$same">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Same</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:variable name="same-total" select="sum($same/Value)" />    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Same Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$same-total"/></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- add -->
        <xsl:variable name="add" select="Document[1]/Downto[not(key('doc2', rec_no ))]" />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$add">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Add</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:variable name="add-total" select="sum($add/Value)" />  
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Add Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$add-total"/></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- delete -->
        <xsl:variable name="delete" select="Document[2]/Downto[not(key('doc1', rec_no ))]" />   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$delete">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Delete</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:variable name="delete-total" select="sum($delete/Value)" />    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Delete Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$delete-total"/></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- grand total -->
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Grand Total</th>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$same-total + $add-total + $delete-total"/></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Downto">
    <xsl:param name="section"/>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$section"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rec_no"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="desc"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="qty"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to the above input will result in:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>RecNo</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Same</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>Desc1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Same</td>
      <td>444</td>
      <td>Desc4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>400.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Same Total</td>
      <th>500</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Add</td>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>Desc3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>300.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Add</td>
      <td>555</td>
      <td>Desc5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>500.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Add Total</td>
      <th>800</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Delete</td>
      <td>222</td>
      <td>Desc2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>200.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Delete</td>
      <td>777</td>
      <td>Desc7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>700.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Delete</td>
      <td>888</td>
      <td>Desc8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>800.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Delete Total</td>
      <th>1700</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Grand Total</th>
      <th>3000</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: I also have one more question regarding grouping Consider the output, i have to group the rec no 333 by their quantities. In the add section the rec 333 should appear once and and their quantities (3+3) should be displayed in one row                                                             Section RecNo Desc Qty Value 
Same 111 Desc1 1 100.00 
Same 444 Desc4 4 400.00 
Same Total 500 
Add 333 Desc3 3 300.00 
Add 333 Desc3 3 300.00 
Add 555 Desc5 5 500.00 
Add Total 1100 
Delete 222 Desc2 2 200.00 
Delete 777 Desc7 7 700.00 
Delete 888 Desc8 8 800.00 
Delete Total 1700 
Grand Total 3300

Comment: @user2822294 I am afraid it's impossible to follow. Perhaps you should post a new question?

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. i will do that.